# Telling an std::thread to kill/stop itself when a condition is met

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

Say I have a worker thread `tWorker`, which is initialized when `Boss` is constructed and tells it to do `work()`, until `bRetired` is true. An `std::mutex`, `mtx`, locks some data (`vFiles`) so that `tWorker` owns it when he's working on it.

How do I make `tWorker` "commit suicide" once `bRetired` becomes `true`? How would the `mutex` be destroyed when the thread stops execution?

I've read that `std::thread` objects cannot be interrupted in any way. Does letting the thread do nothing (or calling `std::this_thread::yield()`) provide the same effect as killing the thread?

```
class Boss {
private:
    std::thread tWorker;
    std::mutex mtx;
    bool bRetired;
    std::vector< std::string > vFiles;

    void work() {
        while ( bRetired == false ) {
            // Do your job!
            mtx.lock();
            // ... Do something about vFiles ...
            mtx.unlock();
        }

        // tWorker has retired, commit suicide
        // ** How? **

        // Does this suffice if I want to "kill" the thread?
        std::this_thread::yield(); 
    }

public:
    Boss() {
        bRetired = false;
        tWorker = std::thread( &Boss::work, this );

        // Have worker do its job independently
        // **Bonus Question** : Should this be tWorker.join() or tWorker.detach()?
        tWorker.detach();
    }

    retire() {
        bRetired = true;
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- The worker thread cannot be started again once it is retired.
- The worker thread works on the background without interrupting the main thread's execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to [`std::thread::yield()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) is unrequired and does not kill the calling thread:

> Provides a hint to the implementation to reschedule the execution of threads, allowing other threads to run.

Just exit the function to exit the thread.

Note that the use of `bRetired` is incorrect as two threads can be accessing the same memory location and one of those threads is modifying it: *this is undefined behaviour*. Also, the change made in the function `retire()`, a different thread, will not be seen by the thread executing `run()`: use [`atomic<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) for atomicity and visibility.

If [`join()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) was used within the constructor the constructor would not return until the thread exited, which would never happen as it would be impossible to call `retire()` because the object would not be available (as the constructor would not have returned). If it is required to synchronize with the exiting of the thread then do not `detach()` but `join()` in the `retire()` function:

```
void retire() {
    bRetired = true;
    tWorker.join();
}
```

Use RAII for acquiring `mutex`es ([`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) for example) to ensure it always released. The `mutex` will be destroyed when it goes out of scope, in this case when its containing class is destructed.

Comment: So, breaking from the `while` loop will stop the thread? Say I added another `bool` which is `bSleep` to make the thread sleep or do nothing until I tell it to (not with a specific amount of time), should I return from the function or use `yield()`?

Comment: @LanceGray, see [`condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) for implementing a _wait until I tell you to do something_ mechanism.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, `std::condition_variable` is similar to `pthread_cond_wait`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, depending on your OS the implementation may use something like this internally.

Answer (score 6):

> How do I make tWorker "commit suicide" once bRetired becomes true?

You let the control flow exit the thread function. That `std::this_thread::yield()` call in unnecessary.

> How would the mutex be destroyed when the thread stops execution?

That mutex is a member of `Boss` class. It gets destroyed in the destructor of `Boss` when the object is getting destroyed.

> I've read that std::thread objects cannot be interrupted in any way.

C++ API does not provide means to terminate an arbitrary thread. There has to be a way to tell a thread to terminate and then wait till it does, as you intend to do.

> Does letting the thread do nothing (or calling std::this_thread::yield()) provide the same effect as killing the thread?

No.

There is a race condition on `bRetired` variable though. It either needs to be `std::atomic<bool>` or it should only be read and modified only when that mutex is locked.